# hadoop cluster - wrong permissions after upgrade

Tags: hadoop

After upgrading my cluster to hadoop-1.0.0 it became impossible to run any jobs successfuly. I'm getting the following error in my jobtracker logs:

```
2012-01-31 10:25:13,558 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskInProgress: Error from attempt_201201310126_0002_m_000005_0: Error initializing attempt_201201310126_0002_m_000005_0:
ENOENT: No such file or directory
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO.chmod(Native Method)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.execSetPermission(FileUtil.java:692)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.setPermission(FileUtil.java:647)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:509)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirs(RawLocalFileSystem.java:344)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobLocalizer.initializeJobLogDir(JobLocalizer.java:239)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.DefaultTaskController.initializeJob(DefaultTaskController.java:196)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker$4.run(TaskTracker.java:1209)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1083)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.initializeJob(TaskTracker.java:1184)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.localizeJob(TaskTracker.java:1099)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker$5.run(TaskTracker.java:2382)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

2012-01-31 10:25:13,558 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskStatus: Trying to set finish time for task attempt_201201310126_0002_m_000005_0 when no start time is set, stackTrace is : java.lang.Exception
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskStatus.setFinishTime(TaskStatus.java:145)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskInProgress.incompleteSubTask(TaskInProgress.java:670)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobInProgress.failedTask(JobInProgress.java:2942)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobInProgress.updateTaskStatus(JobInProgress.java:1159)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.updateTaskStatuses(JobTracker.java:4739)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.processHeartbeat(JobTracker.java:3683)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.heartbeat(JobTracker.java:3378)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:563)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1388)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1384)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1083)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1382)
```

Any my mapreduce logs also have similar error:

```
12/01/31 10:25:44 WARN mapred.JobClient: Error reading task outputhttp://hadoop2:50060/tasklog?plaintext=true&attemptid=attempt_201201310126_0002_r_000000_1&filter=stdout
12/01/31 10:25:44 WARN mapred.JobClient: Error reading task outputhttp://hadoop2:50060/tasklog?plaintext=true&attemptid=attempt_201201310126_0002_r_000000_1&filter=stderr
12/01/31 10:25:47 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201201310126_0002_m_000004_2, Status : FAILED
Error initializing attempt_201201310126_0002_m_000004_2:
ENOENT: No such file or directory
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO.chmod(Native Method)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.execSetPermission(FileUtil.java:692)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.setPermission(FileUtil.java:647)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:509)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirs(RawLocalFileSystem.java:344)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobLocalizer.initializeJobLogDir(JobLocalizer.java:239)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.DefaultTaskController.initializeJob(DefaultTaskController.java:196)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker$4.run(TaskTracker.java:1209)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1083)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.initializeJob(TaskTracker.java:1184)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.localizeJob(TaskTracker.java:1099)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker$5.run(TaskTracker.java:2382)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

It seems to me this is a permissions' related problem, but I don't know where should these be fixed.

My first guess was to check permissions on HDFS for my ${mapred.system.dir} but they seem okey, what's more - the job file for the failing job is being created in it succesfully. The only problem is with "attempt_*" files.

Could somebody point me to a reasonable solution?

Comment: Possibly related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9992566/hadoop-map-reduce-operation-is-failing-on-writing-output

Comment: Hi Marcin, were you able to figure out the issue? I am also facing the same problem. Please comment if you did.

Comment: Same as @pseudocode.