# Hadoop map-reduce operation is failing on writing output

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, debian, file-access

I am finally able to start a map-reduce job on Hadoop (running on a single debian machine). However, the map reduce job always fails with the following error:

```
hadoopmachine@debian:~$ ./hadoop-1.0.1/bin/hadoop jar hadooptest/main.jar nl.mydomain.hadoop.debian.test.Main /user/hadoopmachine/input /user/hadoopmachine/output
Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

12/04/03 07:29:35 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
****hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hadoopmachine/input
12/04/03 07:29:35 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
12/04/03 07:29:35 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201204030722_0002
12/04/03 07:29:36 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
12/04/03 07:29:41 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201204030722_0002_m_000002_0, Status : FAILED
Error initializing attempt_201204030722_0002_m_000002_0:
ENOENT: No such file or directory
at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO.chmod(Native Method)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.execSetPermission(FileUtil.java:692)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.setPermission(FileUtil.java:647)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:509)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirs(RawLocalFileSystem.java:344)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobLocalizer.initializeJobLogDir(JobLocalizer.java:239)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.DefaultTaskController.initializeJob(DefaultTaskController.java:196)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker$4.run(TaskTracker.java:1226)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:416)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1093)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.initializeJob(TaskTracker.java:1201)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.localizeJob(TaskTracker.java:1116)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker$5.run(TaskTracker.java:2404)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)

12/04/03 07:29:41 WARN mapred.JobClient: Error reading task outputhttp://localhost:50060/tasklog?plaintext=true&attemptid=attempt_201204030722_0002_m_000002_0&filter=stdout
12/04/03 07:29:41 WARN mapred.JobClient: Error reading task outputhttp://localhost:50060/tasklog?plaintext=true&attemptid=attempt_201204030722_0002_m_000002_0&filter=stderr
```

Unfortunately, it only says: "ENOENT: No such file or directory", it doesn't say what directory it actually tries to access. Pinging localhost works, and the input directory does exist. The jar location is also correct.

Can anybody give me a pointer on how to fix for this error, or how to find out which file Hadoop is trying to access?

I found several similar problems on the Hadoop mailing list, but no responses on those...

Thanks!

P.S. The config for mapred.local.dir looks like this (in mapred-site.xml):

```
<property>
  <name>mapred.local.dir</name>
  <value>/home/hadoopmachine/hadoop_data/mapred</value>
  <final>true</final>
</property>
```

As requested, the output of ps auxww | grep TaskTracker is:

```
1000      4249  2.2  0.8 1181992 30176 ?       Sl   12:09   0:00
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/bin/java -Dproc_tasktracker -Xmx1000m -Dhadoop.log.dir=/home/hadoopmachine/hadoop-1.0.1/libexec/../logs
-Dhadoop.log.file=hadoop-hadoopmachine-tasktracker-debian.log -Dhadoop.home.dir=/home/hadoopmachine/hadoop-1.0.1/libexec/.. 
-Dhadoop.id.str=hadoopmachine -Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,DRFA -Dhadoop.security.logger=INFO,NullAppender
-Djava.library.path=/home/hadoopmachine/hadoop-1.0.1/libexec/../lib/native/Linux-i386-32 
-Dhadoop.policy.file=hadoop-policy.xml -classpath [ommitted very long list of jars] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker
```

Comment: I see that you are using open jdk 6 --- could that be causing a problem ?  Hadoop i believe is only supported on the sun / oracle jvm.  I'v seen many cryptic sorts of errors related to this on my old hadoop instance running on my open JDK 6 machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the job tracker, identify which hadoop node this task executed on. SSH to that node and identify the location of the `hadoop.log.dir` directory (check the mapred-site.xml for this node) - my guess is the hadoop user does not have the correct permissions to create sub-directories in this folder

The actual folder it's trying to create lies under the ${hadoop.log.dir}/userlogs folder - check this folder has the correct permissions

In your case, looking at the ps output, i'm guessing this is the folder you need to examine the permission of:

```
/home/hadoopmachine/hadoop-1.0.1/libexec/../logs
```

Comment: I checked the location, and the user has rights there (I run all the nodes on localhost, so it is the same machine). So that seems not to be the path that it cannot access.

Comment: I should add that hadoop writes several folders in the mapred.local.dir, so it can definitely find it.. Are there any other important paths?  I've got the ones in the main tutorial all configured...

Comment: which user does the hadoop services run under - does that user have permission (not your local user) - basically can you `su - hadoop` and then perform an mkdir in each of the folders listed? Can you also post the conf property `mapred.local.dir`

Comment: I have no hadoop user, is that a problem? I assume it just runs with the standard user I log in with (its on a "dedicated" virtual machine). I will add the mapred.local.dir config in the question.

Comment: `ps auxww | grep TaskTracker` - what does the first column say as the user? Hadoop typically runs it's services under a single user - this is the user that needs write permissions on the folders in question

Comment: I added the output of that command in the question. I take it from the ps man page that 1000 is the ID of the user? In the passwd file I see that this ID is linked to the user that indeed has the rights on all the folders, so that seems to be ok...

Comment: It turned out to be the userlog dir in the logs dir indeed! It was owned by root. After changing this the errors disappear.